# Kubernetes run pod as root

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to deploy the Hashicorp Vault Helm chart, and I get the following issue: `Error: container's runAsUser breaks non-root policy` is there a way to run Vault as non root? or is there a way to only allow that service to run as root without changing the whole policy?

Comment: Based on [this code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/security_context.go#L87-L92) the only way you can see this error is when `runAsUser: 0` and `runAsNonRoot: true`. Is it what's happening in your case?

Comment: how do i change that?

Comment: Is it what's happening in your case? You should see it in pod object. Run `kubectl get pod <vaultpodname> -oyaml`. Hashicorp Vault helm chart [by default runs as user 100](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/master/templates/server-statefulset.yaml#L48). Did you change any defaults?

Comment: I left everything as default here is the user part of the pod:
fsGroup: 1000
    runAsGroup: 1000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 100

Comment: In such case there shouldn't be any problems. Can you provide detailed step-by-step description how I can replicate your issue?

Comment: I found the issue, it was in the same namspace as my Azure Dev Spaces and there was a conflict there, moved to a new namespace and it was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the issue, it was in the same namespace as my Azure Dev Spaces and there was a conflict there, moved to a new namespace and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

The test container that's the base of the Helm Chart currently works with the directory in /root. So you must run the Chart with `root` or you will have to change the Chart completely.

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /root

ENV BATS_VERSION "1.1.0"

# base packages
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    tar \
    bash \
    openssl \
    python \
    py-pip \
    git \
    jq
```

Comment: is there a way to only run that container as root and leave policy for all the other containers?

Comment: You're free to make how many changes/customizations you need, but in this case, it's not recommended by Hashicorp.

Comment: I mean in the K8s side, because right now it doesn't let me deploy it getting this error " Error: container's runAsUser breaks non-root policy" is there a way to do kind of an exception for this chart?